# How to get the updating list and import to my offline computer?

Tags: apt, repository, download

One of my computers has no Internet connection and it is Ubuntu installed, I try to upgrade it to the latest one, I learn that if it get the latest updating list, it's easy to get the URL of the packages and dependencies by issuing `apt-get --print-uris install <package>` and download them with other computer with Internet connection, then move and install on offline computer, but before that I also wonder how to get and import the updating list to my offline computer?

`apt-get --print-uris update` on my offline computer will list something like `'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_main_cnf_Commands-amd64`, is the package I should download? And how to get it work on my offline computer?

Comment: Can you download and burn an installation CD set? You do not need to (re)install, but you can point your package manager to use the CD's instead of a network connection.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, a chicken-and-egg problem....`--print-uris` can't output anything useful if it doesn't have an up-to-date package list.

If the internet-connected machine has the same `sources.list` configuration as your offline machine **and** has the same packages installed, you can run `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get --print-uris install PACKAGES` (and then download the packages to the USB stick) if you're just installing a few known packages.

Otherwise, you'll need to get the full, up-to-date package lists back to the offline machine.

Package lists are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, so that's where you'll need to copy them to/from.

Run `apt update` on the machine with an internet connection  and copy the package lists onto a USB stick to transfer to the offline machine.

Something along the lines of:

#### On the internet-connected machine:

```
mount "$USB_DEVICE" /mnt
mkdir -p /mnt/lists/

apt update
cp /var/lib/apt/lists/* /mnt/lists/

umount /mnt
```

When you run `cp`, there may be warnings about being unable to copy sub-directories (e.g. `..../partial`).  Just ignore the warnings, they're not important.

#### On the offline machine:

```
mount "$USB_DEVICE" /mnt
cp /mnt/lists/* /var/lib/apt/lists/

apt-get --print-uris dist-upgrade > /mnt/URIs.txt

umount /mnt
```

You can now take the USB stick with URIs.txt on it back to the internet-connected machine and start download the package files, and copy them to the USB stick for transfer back to the offline machine.

Comment: Thank you, good, but, I forget to tell you that the offline and online Ubuntu comes different versions,(18.04 and 20.04) making the thing more complicated.